# I don't understand part of a proof

Tags: proof-writing

I was reading a proof in my textbook today and couldn't figure out why this is true:

$$  nq - mp = nq -mq +mq - mp$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The middle terms, $-mq+mq$ give you $0$.

Comment: $$  nq - mp = nq -mq +mq - mp = nq+(-mq +mq) - mp $$

Comment: Always remember, don't be fooled by variables. It's all math in the end.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align} 
\color{darkgreen}{nq} \color{darkblue}{- mp} 
 & = \color{darkgreen}{nq} \color{darkblue}{- mp} \color{darkred}{ + 0} \\
 & = \color{darkgreen}{nq} \color{darkblue}{- mp} \color{darkred}{ - mq + mq} \\
 & = \color{darkgreen}{nq}  \color{darkred}{ - mq + mq} \color{darkblue}{- mp} 
\end{align}
$$